# Route to absolute URL CakePHP 2.0

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I want to access my sitemap.xml file in /mywebsite/sitemaps/xml/sitemap.xml

Reading some documentation, it is explained that I can reach the absolute URL by using:

```
Router::url('/',true)
```

For some reason it doesn't work. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your site map xml is generated outside of CakePHP, then you can create the folders and file in /mywebsite/app/webroot/sitemaps/xml/sitemap.xml and avoid routing altogether.

If you are dynamically generating the xml through cake, then you don't want to hard-code the route.  Rather, you would route to the controller and action that provide the xml return.  A very basic example would be..

```
Router::connect(
    '/sitemaps/xml/sitemap.xml', 
    array(
        'controller' => 'Xml', 
        'action' => 'sitemap'
    )
);
```

The XML documentation here can help you get started building and routing the site map.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html

Comment: Thanks Scott, exactly what I was looking for. My sitemap is indeed dynamically generetaed